# To run query from Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In my project, I have a snooze button in the table and table is populating the values from database. I have giving a `href` to that button which will open a bootstrap modal dialog.

In modal, I have called the amount of the specific id.

Code for modal is below :

```
<?php
    require_once '../invoice/config.php';
    $reserver = $_GET["id"]; 
    echo $reserver;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name where id = '$reserver'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<form id="modal-form" data-remote="true" method="post" action="saveSnoozeReminder.php?id='<?php echo $reserver ?>'" >
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>SELECT DATE FOR REMINDER </p>
        <label>date</label>
        <input type="date" name="snoozeReminderDate" />
        <label>amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="amt"  value="<?php echo $row['amount']; ?> " disabled >
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="">Snooze</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="window.location.reload()">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now further as the user will select the date, and press on snooze button, I have written another PHP file which will be called on form submit and update the reminder for that specific id in the table.

Another file is named as `saveSnoozeReminder.php` and code for it is :

```
<?php
    require_once '../invoice/config.php';
    $recordid = $_GET["id"];
    echo $recordid;
    $snoozedate = $_POST['snoozeReminderDate'];
    echo $snoozedate;
    $snoozeQuery = "UPDATE paymentremainder SET reminderdate='$snoozedate' WHERE id = $recordid";           
    if (mysqli_query($con, $snoozeQuery)) {
        $message = 'Reminder Snoozed Successfully';
        echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'> 
        alert('$message');
        window.location.replace('index.php');
        </SCRIPT>";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
?>
```

After running this code also, update query isn't getting fired. Is there any way that I can use Ajax or something. Can someone help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current approach, there are few mistakes in `<form>`

1. Don't post `id` along with form action URL `action="saveSnoozeReminder.php?id='<?php echo $reserver ?>'"`, create `hidden` input and add `id` value to it , post it along with form
2. Don't `disable` the input use `readonly`

Form HTML

```
<form id="modal-form" data-remote="true" method="post" action="saveSnoozeReminder.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $reserver ?>">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>SELECT DATE FOR REMINDER </p>
        <label>date</label>
        <input type="date" name="snoozeReminderDate" />
        <label>amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="amt" value="<?php echo $row['amount']; ?> " readonly >
    </div>
    //You don't need to close the modal `data-dismiss="modal"` when submitting the form, it will be auto closed
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit">Snooze</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="window.location.reload()">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in PHP, replace `$_GET` with `$_POST` and use `isset` function

```
<?php
    require_once '../invoice/config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['id'])) { //isset function
        $recordid = $_POST["id"]; //replace $_GET with $POST
        echo $recordid;
        $snoozedate = $_POST['snoozeReminderDate'];
        echo $snoozedate;
        $snoozeQuery = "UPDATE paymentremainder SET reminderdate='$snoozedate' WHERE id = '$recordid'";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $snoozeQuery)) {
            $message = 'Reminder Snoozed Successfully';
                echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'> 
                alert('$message');
                window.location.replace('index.php');
                </SCRIPT>";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
?>
```

This will fix the issues where update query isn't get fired.

**Solution with Ajax**

You asked for alternate Ajax solution.

1. change type of `Snooze` button from `submit` to `button` so form will not submit bydefault and no need to use `e.preventdefault` or `return false` in Ajax Method
2. remove `action="saveSnoozeReminder.php"` from `<form>`
3. give `ids` to input you want to pass values via Ajax and `Snooze` button to bind it with jQuery click function

Form HTML

```
<form id="modal-form" data-remote="true" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="reserverid" value="<?php echo $reserver ?>">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>SELECT DATE FOR REMINDER </p>
        <label>date</label>
        <input type="date" id="snoozeReminderDate" name="snoozeReminderDate" />
        <label>amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="amt" id="amt" value="<?php echo $row['amount']; ?> " readonly >
    </div>
    //You don't need to close the modal `data-dismiss="modal"` Snooze button, otherwise it will close the modal
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="submit" id="Snooze">Snooze</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="window.location.reload()">Close</button>
    </div>
//Ajax message here
<div id="message"></div>
</form>
```

Now The Ajax Method Call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Snooze").click(function () {
        var snoozeid = $('#reserverid').val(); //id of row
        var snoozeReminder = $('#snoozeReminderDate').val(); //date value
        var dataString = 'snoozeid=' + snoozeid + '&snoozeReminder=' + snoozeReminder;
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveSnoozeReminder.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#message").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`$("#message").show(data);` inside form HTML which will show on Ajax response from PHP `saveSnoozeReminder.php`

and the PHP `saveSnoozeReminder.php` will be

```
<?php
    require_once '../invoice/config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['snoozeid'])) {
        $recordid = $_POST["snoozeid"];
        $snoozedate = $_POST['snoozeReminder'];
        $snoozeQuery = "UPDATE paymentremainder SET reminderdate='$snoozedate' WHERE id = '$recordid'";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $snoozeQuery)) {
               echo "<strong>Success!</strong> Everything Is Good.";
        } else {
               echo "<strong>Error!</strong> Something Went Wrong.";
        }
    }
?>
```